# 'stack::n' : cannot access private member declared in class 'stack'

Tags: c++

```
class stack
{
    int n;//problem
    char a[100];//problem
    int top;
   public:
    bool isempty()
      {
        return top == -1;
      }

        stack()
      {
            top=-1;
      }

      bool push(const char &c)
      {
        if(top == 100)
        {
            return false;
        }

        top++;
        a[top] = c;

        return true;

      }

      bool pop(char &c)
      {
        if(top == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

         c = a[top];
         top--;
      }

      char get_top()const
      {
        return a[top];
      }

};
```

> c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\code.cpp(73): error C2248:
>   'stack::n' : cannot access private member declared in class 'stack' 1>
>   c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(20) : see
>   declaration of 'stack::n' 1>          c:\users\tri\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(19) : see
>   declaration of 'stack' 1>c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\code.cpp(76): error C2248:
>   'stack::n' : cannot access private member declared in class 'stack' 1>
>   c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(20) : see
>   declaration of 'stack::n' 1>          c:\users\tri\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(19) : see
>   declaration of 'stack' 1>c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\code.cpp(78): error C2248:
>   'stack::a' : cannot access private member declared in class 'stack' 1>
>   c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(21) : see
>   declaration of 'stack::a' 1>          c:\users\tri\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(19) : see
>   declaration of 'stack' 1>c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\code.cpp(79): error C2248:
>   'stack::a' : cannot access private member declared in class 'stack' 1>
>   c:\users\tri\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(21) : see
>   declaration of 'stack::a' 1>          c:\users\tri\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\projects\assignment01\assignment01\headerfile.h(19) : see
>   declaration of 'stack'

Comment: we are going to need to see `code.cpp` to know whats wrong

Comment: fseek(fp1 , 0L , SEEK_END);
 s.n = ftell(fp1);
 fseek(fp1 , 0L , SEEK_SET);

 for(int i = 0 ; i < s.n ; i++)
 {
  fscanf(fp1 , "%c" , &s.a[i]);                            //Read FILE
  fprintf(fp2 , "%c" , s.a[i]);                           //Write FILE
 }

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code.cpp, my guesses are:

1. You're trying to access private members from outside the class. This is not possible. Mark them as public, or build public functions into the class to access them.
2. You may be attempting to access class members that are not static. If they're not static, you cannot access them with `stack::`. You must instantiate an object of type `stack` first, and then you may access them with the `.` accessor applied to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have done something like this:

```
Stack s;
int num = s.n;
char c = s.a[11];
```

You can't directly assess private members from outside the class. And there is few circumstances we need to assess variables randomly in a stack.